# Does anyone have a PowerShell script to batch encode files using Expression Encoder 3?

Tags: powershell, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I have a set of WMV files that I need to convert to H.264. I have Expression Encoder 3 and can do each through the UI. Just trying to find a script to batch it through PowerShell using the Encoder 3 SDK. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import-module ExpressionEncoder
ls | Convert-Media -VC1IISSmoothStreamingSD480pVBR -TemplateBlackGlass -Output $home\desktop
```

Source: http://blog.johndeutscher.com/2009/07/13/expression-encoder-3-0-and-powershell-scripting-the-api/